# Nginx not forwarding port 80 correctly for specific directory

Tags: apache2, nginx, port-forwarding

Ok

I have Confluence running under Ubuntu 16.04.  I now have JIRA running as well on the same server. Nginx is forwarding port 8090 to port 80 without issue for Confluence so I can just goto domain/confluence. I set up JIRA to work this way as well.

I keep getting a `404 Not Found` error from Nginx.

When I tail the Nginx error log, I am seeing this:

```
2016/07/01 17:27:29 [error] 50688#50688: *2 open() "/usr/share/nginx/html/jira" failed (2: No such file or directory), client: xx.xx.xx.xx, server: www.xxxxxx.net, request: "GET /jira HTTP/1.1", host: "xxxxx.net"
```

I know why this error is happening but I cannot for the life of me figure out where Nginx is getting the path its looking for from. Its technically passing the traffic correctly to Apache but its appending `/jira` to the end of the default directory which is resulting in the 404 not found because that location literally does not exist.

Where is Nginx reading the default location from?

I removed everything in my `sites-available` and `sites-enabled` directories minus the one needed to set up the forwarding. Apache also has no sites in either of its directories.  I checked the Nginx.conf and I dont see that path there.  I have restarted all of my services as well.

**Confluence sites-enabled config**

```
root@confluence:/etc/nginx/sites-enabled# cat confluence
server {

listen www.xxxx.net:80;
    server_name www.xxxx.net;
    location /confluence {
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Host $host;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Server $host;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
        proxy_pass http://localhost:8090/confluence;
    }
}
```

**JIRA sites-enabled config**

```
root@confluence:/etc/nginx/sites-enabled# cat jira
    server {
        listen www.xxxx.net:80;
        server_name www.xxxx.net;
        location /jira {
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Host $host;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Server $host;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
        proxy_pass http://localhost:8080/jira;
        client_max_body_size 10M;
    }
}
```

I am at a loss!!

**EDIT**

So it seems like Nginx is reading this from this file:

`/etc/nginx/sites-available/default`

The issue here, is this file no longer exists. I have stopped/started/reloaded Nginx. Its still wanting to append that directory before the `/jira`.

Comment: Check `/etc/nginx/sites-enabled`.  Is a symlink to the default config file present there?

Comment: The only thing present in that directory are the two files outlined above.

Answer (score 0):

To resolve this, I ended up removing Nginx all together. I only had two server blocks setup so it wasnt a big deal to restore everything.

Once I installed Nginx and setup my server blocks, everything was working fine.

`apt-get purge nginx`
`apt-get install nginx`

I can see how this might not be the best thing but it resolved my issue none the less.

Also instead of having two separate server blocks I configured one as such:

```
    server {
    listen www.xxxx.net:80;
    server_name www.xxxx.net;
    location / {

    location /confluence {
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Host $host;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Server $host;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
        proxy_pass http://localhost:8090/confluence;
        }

    location /jira {
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Host $host;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Server $host;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
        proxy_pass http://localhost:8080/jira;
        client_max_body_size 10M;
        }
    }
}
```

It was important that I added the base location `location /` as without this I wasnt allowed to have my locations set as `/confluence /jira`  Having them without the base location resulted in this error:

`location "/jira" is outside location`